# how to solve this import org.info4

Tags: java

This is a screenshot from my Eclipse program about Powell and Welsh I tried to download the package but I didn't find the way.

[image: pic]

Comment: Please recheck your jar file included or not

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is a Java compilation error. 
It means that you are missing some jar files in your classpath.
The following seems to be location on the GitHub of the program you are looking for.

https://github.com/Andriantomanga/welsh-powell-graphic-impl

Create an account on GitHub and tried to clone the source, then import it into your eclipse.

Comment: One does not need to register at GitHub to clone over HTTPS or download a ZIP snapshot.